# Multiple Vimeo players using Froogaloop written in vanillajs

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

I'm attempting to use Vimeo's api to control multiple players on one page.
I would like to use Froogaloop's libarary for this but I dont know how to get it to work WITHOUT jQuery.

Below is my attempt which fails to work as `vimeoPlayer.el[i].addEvent is not a function`

```js
var vimeoPlayer = {
    el: document.querySelectorAll('.video iframe'),

    init: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < vimeoPlayer.el.length; i++) {
            vimeoPlayer.el[i].addEvent('ready', function() {
                console.log('ready');
                vimeoPlayer.el[i].addEvent('play', vimeoPlayer.onPlay);
                vimeoPlayer.el[i].addEvent('finish', vimeoPlayer.onFinish);
            });
        }

    },
    onPlay: function(){
        console.log('play');
    },
    onFinish: function(){
        console.log('finished');
    }
};
vimeoPlayer.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've since worked out a solution below:

```js
var vp = {
    el: document.querySelectorAll('.video-fit.--overlay iframe'),

    init: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < vp.el.length; i++) {
            Froogaloop( vp.el[i] ).addEvent('ready', vp.onReady);
        }
    },
    onReady: function(playerID){
        var froogaloop = $f(playerID);
        froogaloop.addEvent('play', vp.onPlay);
        froogaloop.addEvent('finish', vp.onFinish);
        froogaloop.addEvent('pause', vp.onPause);
        console.log('ready', playerID);
        var videoComponet = document.querySelector('#' + playerID).parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.component-block__fill .video-action');

        videoComponet.addEventListener('click', function(){
            froogaloop.api('play');
        },false);

    },
    onPlay: function(playerID){
        console.log('play', playerID);
        var overlay = document.querySelector('#' + playerID).parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.component-block__fill');
        overlay.classList.add('--hidden');
    },
    onPause: function(playerID){
        console.log('stop', playerID);
        var overlay = document.querySelector('#' + playerID).parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.component-block__fill');
        overlay.classList.remove('--hidden');
    },
    onFinish: function(playerID){
        vp.onPause(playerID);
    }
};

vp.init();
```

```html
<?php

function videoBlock ($video ,$count){
 $videohtml = $video['video'];
 $addString = '?api=1&player_id=player' . $count;

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($videohtml);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = $old_src . $addString;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
  $tag->setAttribute('id', 'player' . $count);
    }
    $videohtml = $doc->saveHTML();
 ?>

 <section class="component-block mt1">
  <div class="video-fit --overlay">
   <?= $videohtml ?>
  </div>
  <div class="component-block__fill">
   <div class="component-block__background" style="background-image:url('<?= $video[poster][sizes][large]?>');"><!-- --></div>
   <div class="component-block__details --center">
    <span class="video-action btn red">Play</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
<?php } ?>
```